# jQuery hover scale from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is certainly going to be an easy one but I can't get my head around what I am doing wrong...

I am trying to do a hover effect on a UL that affects a link within one of the UL LI's.

My current code looks like this:

```
$("ul.punchlines").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("li a.light-grey-gradient").animate({'width' : '60%','top':'-65px'});
});
$("ul.punchlines").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find("li a.light-grey-gradient").animate({'width' : '30%','top':'0px'});
});
```

This technically works as it gives the effect that the base of the element to be scaled remains in place and scales up from the bottom however it does it in two stages, I am trying to get this effect to happen all in one motion so it is a seamless scale and move.

I can do this easily with basic CSS3 transitions but as it is not supported in IE9 I am trying to use jQuery to allow for maximum browser support.

Can anyone offer a little support firstly about how I get the animation to happen in one motion (not staggered) and secondly if this is the right approach? I am new to jquery and only just getting my hands dirty with it  :-)

Comment: Have you tried positioning absolute the `light-grey-gradient` and setting `bottom` to `0` but positioning relative the parent container? If you could prepare a fiddle it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see JQuery hover api:

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

also make sure that your "li" have absolute position.

```
$("ul.punchlines").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("li a.light-grey-gradient").animate({'width' : '60%','top':'-65px'});
}, function () {
    $(this).find("li a.light-grey-gradient").animate({'width' : '30%','top':'0px'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the much cleaner code, I got there thanks to this.